# Mercurial security and google accounts

Tags: mercurial, google-account

Does anyone have experiences to manage security in Mercurial with Google accounts, I would like to create public repository but i want to share it with some google users. 
No one other should know anything about my repository.
Thanks for advice

Comment: If you can do OpenID auth, or use OAuth, it shouldn't be too hard (can be done at the webserver level).

Comment: Hi Tonfa, thanks could you please provide link to help page how to do it thanks.

Comment: http://findingscience.com/mod_auth_openid/ from a quick google, but you should probably look a bit more in details at what the options are. http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Configuring_Apache (6.3) will be similar expect you will use openid module.